# Could not understand the output of !! in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I added !! in the end of echo command, it gave some output but I am unable to understand the output of the command. What does !! actually do in Linux?

Comment: >> echo adarsh !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your example is something like this:

```
echo hello!!
```

The answer depends on what shell you are using. Assuming bash merely because this is what I usually use:

From bash man page:

```
!!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'.
```

This means that the command above will print `hello` followed by the previous command line from shell command history.

Answer (score 3):

!!           Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'

Comment: so both **echo hello !!** and **echo hello !-1** will do the same things?